# How to write a C program that compiles other C programs using GCC?

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04

I want my program to do the same thing as the terminal commands below:

```
gcc program1.c -o p1 funcs.c

gcc program2.c -o p1 funcs.c
```

This is what I've been experimenting with: [Making a C program to compile another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203111/making-a-c-program-to-compile-another)

I got as far so calling my program (`./"programName"`) in the terminal that it replaced the need for me too type `gcc` but needing me too type in the rest.

Comment: too broad.. and requires lots of effort.

Comment: _"This is what I´ve been experimenting with"_. And what problem(s) did you run into? It's unclear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Linux and POSIX APIs so read first [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)

You could just run a compilation command with [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), you can use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to build the command string (but beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)); for example

```
void compile_program_by_number (int i) {
   assert (i>0);
   char cmdbuf[64];
   memset(cmdbuf, 0, sizeof(cmdbuf));
   if (snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf),
               "gcc -Wall -g -O program%d.c fun.c -o p%d",
               i, i) 
         >= sizeof(cmdbuf)) {
       fprintf(stderr, "too wide command for #%d\n", i);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   };
   fflush(NULL); // always useful before system(3)
   int nok = system(cmdbuf);
   if (nok) {
      fprintf(stderr, "compilation %s failed with %d\n", cmdbuf, nok);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

BTW, your program could generate some C code, then `fork` + `execve` + `waitpid` the `gcc` compiler (or `make`), then perhaps even [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) the result of the compilation (you'll need `gcc -fPIC -shared -O foo.c -o foo.so` to compile a `dlopen`able shared object...). [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is doing exactly that. (and so does my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) which shows that you can do a big lot of `dlopen`-s ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` family function or you can directly execute shell command by using `system()` method

Answer (score 0):

There is build in functionality in Makefile.

All you would have to call is `make`.

How to: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Great stackoverflow question: [How do I make a simple makefile for gcc on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-gcc-unix)